# Offline Password Manager

Tags: apps, security, internet, password, organization

Is there an existing app that helps you keep, encrypt and organize passwords **WITHOUT** requiring internet access? Of course not necessarily free.

The reason for not accepting internet access requirement is elevated security (read paranoia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinKey](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=e827d5bc-dbc1-4a4d-9b57-7beb693e3487) seems to be what you are looking for, as it does not request permission to access data services. Additionally, it seems to be open source and compatible to the popular KeePass desktop software.

Comment: Bitter-sweet feeling, this app is what I need but requires 8.1 which is not out yet (not as a preview but as a final version).

Comment: Oh well, I'll try to write a small one for me..

Comment: .. or since it is open source I could fork it.

Answer (score -1):

[LastPass](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=9b86eadc-16e8-df11-9264-00237de2db9e) is a very famous password manager.

Comment: I'm sorry this **DOES** require data services (i.e. internet access).